# How to remove subdocument (by Id) embedded in sub array in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, pull, subdocument

```
ProductCollection: 
{
  _id: { ObjectId('x1')},
  products: [ 
              { listPrice: '1.90', product: {id: 'xxx1'} },
              { listPrice: '3.90', product: {id: 'xxx2'} },
              { listPrice: '5.90', product: {id: 'xxx3'} }
            ]
},
{
  _id: { ObjectId('x2')},
  products: [ 
              { listPrice: '2.90', product: {id: 'xxx4'} },
              { listPrice: '4.90', product: {id: 'xxx5'} },
              { listPrice: '5.90', product: {id: 'xxx6'} }
            ]
},
```

I want to remove subdocument (xxx3) from collection (x1), and try below:

```
ProductCollection.update(
{ 
  "_id": mongoose.Types.ObjectId('x1')  
}, 
{ 
  $pull : { 'products.product': {id: 'xxx3' } } 
}
```

It just doesn't seem to work. Can anyone please help me? Thank you

Comment: It should be `{ $pull : { 'products': { 'product.id': 'xxx3' } } }`

Comment: @Winzlet:  I tried (seems similar to kmreko advise below, except with quote for 'products'). It gave same result and throws me this error: UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: CastError: Cast to ObjectId failed for value "xxx1" at path "product". Next, I tried also: $pull : { 'products': { 'product._id': mongoose.Types.ObjectId('5baa131b36d6a02b442b4b5e') } }. There is no error this time, but nothing happen. The subdocument is still there, anything went wrong here? Thank you

Comment: @Winzlet: Same advise to above, I switch to match to '_id' using this code: $pull : { products: { 'product': { 5baa131b36d6a02b442b4b5e }  } }. It works perfectly. Thank you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The field for [`$pull`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/pull/) needs to be the array.

This should work:

```
$pull: { products: { 'product.id': 'xxx3' } }
```

Comment: I tried, but it throws me this error: UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: CastError: Cast to ObjectId failed for value "xxx1" at path "product". Next,  I tried also: $pull : { 'products': { 'product._id': mongoose.Types.ObjectId('5baa131b36d6a02b442b4b5e') } }. There is no error this time, but nothing happen. The subdocument is still there, anything went wrong here? Thank you

Comment: I think your advise is correct, and I switch to match to '_id' using this code: $pull : { products: { 'product': { 5baa131b36d6a02b442b4b5e }  } }. It works perfectly. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

add this `_id: {id: false}` while creating mongoose schema

for eg:

```js
partners:[{
    name: { type: String, default: '' },
    logo: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.Mixed, default: '' },
    _id: { id: false }
  }],
```